# Use Object or String from other Sub VB6

Tags: string, object, vb6

How to make it's possible in vb6, for example i want to show result in Sub Action() and on Btn1_Click() but i set all required Object and String on Form_Load():

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim ObjFso As Object
Dim TheText As String
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
TheText = "Hello"
Call Action
End Sub

Public Sub Action()
ObjFso.CreateTextFile("Test.txt").WriteLine(TheText)
MsgBox TheText, 0, "This is the text"
End Sub

Private Sub Btn1_Click()
If ObjFso.OpenTextFile("Test.Txt",1).ReadLine = TheText Then
MsgBox "Success", 64, "Ok"
Else
MsgBox "Fail", 16, "Ouch"
End If
End Sub
```

- Are it's possible that the script creating text file "Test.txt" with "Hello" text inside?
- Are it's possible to show MsgBox with "Hello" text?
- Are it's possible when i press Btn1 i got "Success" Message Box?
- **Note:** I ask this because i don't know about vb6 arguments like `Call TheSub(arguments)`, i just know arguments in **VBS** but not in **VB6**, so please don't close this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference with any other modern language.

You can decalare '`Dim TheText As String`' globally at the beginning of the form code.So you  can access it in any Sub or Function of the form.

Also you can call CallAction like `CallAction(theText)` using as a parameter.Your CallAction sub will be

```
public sub CallAction(text as String)
msgbox text
end sub
```

Comment: Button_Click() is automatically triggered sub for a button action.You can't have parameter in it.To use theText in on Button_Click() theText has to be declared globally in the form.

Comment: uh oh, thanks for answer, i'll try this... :), but i don't understand about declare thetext string for use in btn click :(

Comment: declare theText out of Form_Load, so it will be global and you can access it any sub and function.